# SQL Combine multiple rows from same table into one row with different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that currently returns 2 rows (it will always only return 2 rows).

```
Select
    User_Profile.userid, User_Profile.displayname, User_Profile.picPath,
    Battle.id as battleid, Battle.challenger_id as challengerid,
    Video.[filename]
From 
    Battle
INNER Join  
    User_Profile ON Battle.challenger_id = User_Profile.userid OR
                    Battle.challenged_id = User_Profile.userid
INNER Join
    Video ON User_Profile.userid = Video.[user_id]
WHERE
    Video.battle_id = Battle.id
```

This returns something like this:

```
userid | displayname | picPath  | battleid | challengerid | filename
--------------------------------------------------------------------
6      | CandyPoo   | test.jpg  |   12     | 9            | test.mp4
9      | Nawlrus    | test2.jpg |   12     | 9            | test2.mp4
```

I am looking to return something like this:

```
battleid | challengerid | xuserid | xdisplayname | xpicPath  | xfilename | Yuserid | YdisplayName | YpicPath | YfileName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12       | 9            |  9      | Nawlrus      | test2.jpg | test2.mp4 | 6       | CandyPoo     | test.jpg | test.mp4
```

Is there any way to do this?  I will be returning multiple rows like the one above (Top X) but the rows with the same battleid will need to be merged like the table you see above.  Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that your query will always return only two rows. If that truly is the case, then you could use `row_number()` to assign a sequence value to each row and then use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to convert the rows into columns:

```
select battleid,
  challengerId,
  max(case when seq = 1 then userid end) xUserId,
  max(case when seq = 1 then displayname end) xDisplayName,
  max(case when seq = 1 then picPath end) xPicPath,
  max(case when seq = 1 then filename end) xFileName,
  max(case when seq = 2 then userid end) yUserId,
  max(case when seq = 2 then displayname end) yDisplayName,
  max(case when seq = 2 then picPath end) yPicPath,
  max(case when seq = 2 then filename end) yFileName
from
(
  Select User_Profile.userid, 
    User_Profile.displayname, 
    User_Profile.picPath,
    Battle.id as battleid, 
    Battle.challenger_id as challengerid,
    Video.[filename],
    row_number() over(partition by battle.id order by user_profile.userid) seq
  From Battle
  INNER Join User_Profile 
    ON Battle.challenger_id = User_Profile.userid 
    OR Battle.challenged_id = User_Profile.userid
  INNER Join Video 
    ON User_Profile.userid = Video.[user_id]
    AND Video.battle_id = Battle.id
) src
group by battleid, challengerId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to the below where you declare the initial select and then join it back on itself where you distinguish between the userid's

```
;with
    GetData as
    (
        Select
        User_Profile.userid as userid, User_Profile.displayname as displayname
            ,User_Profile.picPath as picpath,
        Battle.id as battleid, Battle.challenger_id as challengerid,
        Video.[filename] as vfilename
        From Battle
        INNER Join  
        User_Profile ON Battle.challenger_id = User_Profile.userid OR
        Battle.challenged_id = User_Profile.userid
        INNER Join
        Video ON User_Profile.userid = Video.[user_id]
        WHERE
        Video.battle_id = Battle.id
    )
    SELECT battleid, challengerid
           ,a.userid as xuserid, a.displayname as xdisplayname, a.picpath as xpicpath
           ,a.vfilename as xfilename
           ,b.userid as yuserid, b.displayname as ydisplayname, b.picpath as ypicpath
           ,b.vfilename as yfilename
    FROM GetData a
    JOIN GetData b on a.battleid = b.battleid and a.userid != b.userid
```